# How to do multi-word brace expansion for command-line flags

Tags: shell, zsh, brace-expansion

If you have a command that takes an argument with a value often you can do something like:

```
journalctl -u{rspamd,postfix}
# Expands to: journalctl -urspamd -upostfix


journalctl --unit={rspamd,postfix}
# Expands to: journalctl --unit=rspamd --unit=postfix
```

However some commands don't support arguments concatenated like that and require `--unit rspamd --unit postfix`. Is there a clean way to expand multiple values of these flag using brace expansion? Obviously the following doesn't work:

```
journalctl --unit {rspamd,postfix}
# Expands to: journalctl --unit rspamd postfix
```

Answer (score 3):

As long as the additional arguments don't themselves contain whitespace, you can do something like

```
journalctl ${(z):---unit {rspamd,postfix}}
```

The parameter expansion uses the `z` flag to perform word-splitting on the result of the parameter expansion. The brace expansion includes the space in the brace expansion because the expression following `:-` is not subject to word-splitting. As a result, the entire parameter expansion (which, yes, doesn't actually *involve* a parameter) produces 4 words: `--unit`, `rspamd`, `--unit`, and `postfix`.

Answer (score 0):

How about quote the space character with [`print -z`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print)?

```
% print -z journalctl --unit' '{rspamd,postfix}
% journalctl --unit rspamd --unit postfix
```

Or even escape it with `\`:

```
% print -z journalctl --unit\ {rspamd,postfix}
% journalctl --unit rspamd --unit postfix
```

---

[`print -z`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print):

> -z
>
> Push the arguments onto the editing buffer stack, separated by
> spaces.
>
> --- [zshbultins(1),  zsh built-in command, print](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print)